# Calculus Integral and Reduction formula

Tags: calculus, integration

[image]

For the first part I was thinking that since the function is even and the integral is from -2 to 2 then the negative part will cancel out the positive part. Is that the right thinking?

for the reduction formula i understand how to do it, the only part that is throwing me off is the x^(2k-2), why would it be 2k-2 and not 2k-1?

Comment: The argument for the first will work, except we need to use fact that the function is **odd**, not even.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is correct, for the first: but you mixed up parity: the function is odd, and hence the value of the integral from $-2$ to $0$ will cancel the value from $0$ to $2$.

For the second part, note that we subtract $1$ from $\bf k$: $\quad x^{2(k-1)} = x^{2k - 2}$

We are letting $n = 2k$, $k>0$, to ensure we have an even exponent: $k = 1, n = 2;\;\;k = 2\to n = 2k = 4;\;\cdots \;k = j \to n = 2j$.

Comment: oh okay, so the cancelling out works for odd functions?

Comment: Yes, indeed, we get a negative value from $-2 \to 0$ which is equal in magnitude to the positive value from $0 \to 2$. So net value is $0$